# Ajax after success, how to pass data to a variable to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have script like this

```
 function getval(sel) {
         var id= sel.value;  
                $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"./tab.php",
                        data:{id:id,task:'search'},
                         success: function(response){
                             //(I don't know what i should write for pass to php code)
                         }
            });
    }
```

I don't know how I can pass data `response` to php code ?
For Example: if I `alert response`, it's show `123` .so I want pass value `123` to a variable in php 
`$id = 123`

Comment: Send it with a new ajax call?

Comment: You can't do that unless you use ajax and send it again... but since the variable is already coming from PHP, what's the point? You should do all the execution in 1 php file instead of making multiple requests.

Comment: Do the thing you want to do in tab.php

Comment: @AndreasFurster Presuming it's the same file

Comment: What do you actually want to do? You sent the id to post.php. What are you doing in post.php?

Comment: PHP is returning the value in the first place, so why do you need to send it back to the server?

Comment: @Doctus I do search from select-box, I have list data in table already but I want when user select on my select-box, it's query to select data to show in list again

Answer (score 0):

`response` is the result passed BY php, not TO php. What's passed to php is the `id` and the `task`.

In your `tab.php`, you can access these two values :

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$task = $_POST['task'];
//do anything you want with it...
?>
```

Comment: it's not what I asking

Comment: Then I suggest to edit your question to make it more clear, I'm not alone to think that's what was asked..

Comment: this is what I asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513808/php-how-to-used-select-box-for-search-data-in-list-view-table

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right workflow. PHP executes on runtime, so every time the page has finished loading you can't really put variables back into PHP (unless you reload the page). This is where AJAX comes in, so you can call PHP scripts from JavaScript / jQuery and don't have to reload the page every time.

The right thing to do is to either store the variable you have generated in the `tab.php` script in a database, $_SESSION, $_COOKIE or something similar like so:

```
//put this at the top of all your php scripts you want to use the variable in
session_start();
//now store the variable you wanted to pass (in tab.php)
$_SESSION['returnValue'] = $myValue;
```

Now if you want to use the variable in other pages just echo it like so (remember to add `session_start()` at the top of the PHP script.

```
echo $_SESSION['returnValue'];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, start by reading [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

To answer your question,

```
function getval(sel) {
   var id= sel.value;  
   $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"./tab.php",
      data:{id:id,task:'search'},
      success: function(response){
         //(I don't know what i should write for pass to php code)
      }
    });
}
```

The result from `id` and `task` are sent via `$_POST` (type:"POST") to the page `tab.php` (url:"./tab.php"). If you want to do that on a different page, just change the url in your ajax call: url:"./any_other_page.php" and the posted values will be sent there

Finally, read [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) post as well. It is greatly written and very well explained.

Hope it helps!

Keep on coding! 

Ares.

Comment: `id` that I pass to `tab.php` is a variable for pass to get `id` to query to get data in this page

Comment: I understood 50% of what you just said... you have to pass `id` with $_GET to a different page?

Comment: I have ask it again with it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513808/php-how-to-used-select-box-for-search-data-in-list-view-table