# php how to used select box for search data in list view (table)

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, postgresql

I have a query to select data from table(database) to show in List-view (table), than I want make code search data in list-view(table) by select-box without button submit.

this is my code in select box

```
<select onchange="selectrun(this);"> 
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

And this is my scrip

```
function selectrun(sel){
           var id= sel.value;  
            $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"./tab.php",
                    data:{id:id,task:'search'},
                     success: function(response){
                         //(I don't know what i should write for pass to php code)
                         //what I return in response is a query because I want it's execute at my main page,that why I want pass it to $querr_select in php code but I don know my solution is good or not because I never do with ajax   
                     }
        });

}
```

This is my code in main page

```
$query_select = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
$result=pg_query($query_select ) or die(pg_last_error());
while($row_info=pg_fetch_array($result)){ 
   //code for display view
}
```

*Note: in tab.php,I just pass `id` from main page to page `tab.php` for write a query to select in condition in where; when I alert `response` I get `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID ='1'`  And I want pass it to `$query_select`, is my idea but not work yet :(

Comment: When the JS asks the server for a response, what do you want to do with that response?

Comment: @Popnoodles, truth I never hear autocomplete in before, thank you , may be because I just start with my studying programming

Comment: i deleted that comment because it may not be what you want

Comment: Why is this tagged MySQL when you're very clearly using Postgres?

Comment: in page `tab.php`, I nothing complicate, I just write a query have condition, and want return it's back for my parameter `$$query_select`  get it for run to show data , anyways my goal is do searching

Comment: @tadman yes is my misstate, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is how to display the result of an Ajax query. Is that correct?

```
<select onchange="selectrun(this);"> 
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
<!-- A new HTML div for displaying Ajax call response: -->
<div id="response-area"></div>

<script>
function selectrun(sel){
           var id= sel.value;  
            $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"./tab.php",
                    data:{id:id,task:'search'},
                     success: function(response){
                        //Jquery sends response to browser div by setting html.
                        $('#response-area').html(response);
                     }
        });

}
</script>
```

tab.php:
A basic concept of how you might return HTML via Ajax. This isn't great programming in terms of mixing HTML and PHP, but it it probably does what you want.

Assuming that your database table contains fields called 'field1' and 'field2', you can iterate through the array using the field names as array keys. Note that pg_fetch_array has additional parameters to select an associative array rather than a numerically indexed one.

```
<?php
    $query_select = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
    $result=pg_query($query_select ) or die(pg_last_error());
    echo "<table>";
    while($row_info=pg_fetch_array($result, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC)){ 
       echo "<tr>
                <td>
                      $row_info[field1]
                </td>
                <td>
                      $row_info[field2]
                </td>
              </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

The modified code above should show you the response returned from tab.php when you change the option selected.

Comment: @@fred2  How about my old data in list-view (table)?

Comment: @start ... I'm not 100% certain what you want, but I have edited the post to provide what I think you are asking for.